# How to create dynamic alias (Conditional command) in bash?

Tags: bash, if-statement, visual-studio-code

I want to create shortcut for 'code file' (VS Code) if there's a second argument, or 'clear' if there's none in a single command line, but i don't know how the bash syntax works.

By looking at the mkcd (mkdir & cd) shortcut that i created:

```
function mkcd {
  if [ ! -n "$1" ]; then
    echo "Enter a directory name"
  elif [ -d $1 ]; then
    echo "\`$1' already exists"
  else
    mkdir $1 && cd $1
  fi
}
```

I tried to do the same, but the error shows 'syntax error near unexpected token `else''

```
function c {
  if $1 then 
    code $1
  else
    clear
  fi
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax error is that `if $1 then` is missing a semi-colon (e.g. `if $1; then`) but read on... There are no "shortcut"s in UNIX. There are scripts, functions, and aliases. It looks like you want to create a function named `c` to call some command named `code` when an argument is given, some other command named `clear` otherwise. That'd be:

```
c() {
    if (( $# > 0 )); then
        code "$*"
    else
        clear
    fi
}
```